# Apache2.4 Fast CGI Parameters like nginx

Tags: fastcgi, php-7, apache2.4

Nginx configuration allow to set params for fastcgi server for each site separately:

```
    location ~ \.(php)$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "open_basedir=/home/***";
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "session.save_path=/home/***/tmp";
        include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

How to do this in the Apache2.4 configuration?
My variant to improve is:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c> 
   AddHandler php7.fcgi .php 
   Action php7.fcgi /php7.fcgi 
   Alias /php7.fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.fcgi 
   FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600 
   <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
       Require all granted
   </Directory> 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this?  I too would like to know.

Comment: Actually, looks like this might work in newer versions of Apache https://serverfault.com/questions/788344/how-to-specify-fastcgi-parameters-with-apache-mod-proxy-fcgi